# Is there a way to animate the plane wrapping into a cylinder (and also the curves of the plane folding into a cylinder)?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I would like to animate (continuously) a plane with any number of curves on it folding into a cylinder (and also seeing the resulting curves -*arbitrary curves, really*- in the cylinder - folded lines would be the geodesics of the cylinder, circles would be sort of pseudo-geodesics, and so on). I've thought a lot about this problem but haven't found any way to actually implement what I'm thinking of (I don't even know if there is really a way, so it's worth asking). I'm aware it's simple to do this without the curves part, but I haven't been able to adapt it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Wrapping a rectangle to form a cylinder](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14828/13)

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov That's exactly why I wrote: "I'm aware it's simple to do this without the curves part, but I haven't been able to adapt it."

Comment: Please provide an example of what exactly you want to wrap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I take the solution from the linked QA, but slightly change the parametrization:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  {Sinc[a u] u, v, 1/a - Cos[a u]/a}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
  ImageSize -> {300, 300}, Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#4 - #5 &},
  BoxRatios -> {3 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], 4}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-\[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, {0, 2 \[Pi]}, {0, 4}},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.7], Orange, Specularity[White, 50]],
  ViewPoint -> {0, 1, -2}, ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0},
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Opacity[.3]]
  ],
 {{a, .01, "wrap"}, 0.001, 1}
 ]
```

This way we start with a 2Pi*2Pi sheet in the x-y plane with one vertex fixed at (0,0,0). Slots `#4` and `#5` correspond to the x-y coordinates of that sheet (not the 3-d space), I'll call them `u` and `v`. Let's say, we want to look at how the line `u - v == 0` wraps into a cylinder. We pass the `MeshFunction -> {#4 - #5 &}` option (alternatively, we could write `Function[{x,y,z,u,v}, u - v]`) for the left hand side of the equation `u - v == 0.` and pass `Mesh -> {{0.}}` for the right hand side.

Check it out.

[image]

As far as the question in the comments goes: In my example the sheet is in (0,0)-(2Pi,2Pi). Let's say, we want to put a spiral in the center, in terms of `u` and `v` it would be `{u[t], v[t]} == {Pi + t/10 Cos[t], Pi + t/10 Sin[t]}.

We use the very same expression as for the sheet above:

```
Function[{u,v}, {Sinc[a u] u, v, 1/a - Cos[a u]/a}]
```

and apply it to the parametric definition of the spiral like so:

```
Function[{u, v}, {Sinc[a u] u, v, 1/a - Cos[a u]/a}] @@ {
      Pi + t/10 Cos[t], Pi + t/10 Sin[t]}

Manipulate[
 Show[{
   ParametricPlot3D[{Sinc[a u] u, v, 1/a - Cos[a u]/a}, {u, 0, 
     2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
    ImageSize -> {300, 300}, Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#4 - #5 &}, BoxRatios -> {3 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], 4},
    PlotRange -> {{-\[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, {0, 2 \[Pi]}, {0, 4}}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.7],
      Orange, Specularity[White, 50]], ViewPoint -> {0, 1, -2}, 
    ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0},
    BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Opacity[.3]]],

   ParametricPlot3D[
    Function[{u, v}, {Sinc[a u] u, v, 1/a - Cos[a u]/a}] @@ {
      Pi + t/10 Cos[t], Pi + t/10 Sin[t]},
    {t, 0, 10 Pi}]

   }], {{a, .01, "wrap"}, 0.001, 1}]
```

[image]

Here is the generalized approach for arbitrary-sized sheets. I've included `k` and `h` as parameters that determine the size of the sheet in the `Manipulate` to yield a sheet sized `2 Pi k` by `h`

```
Manipulate[Show@{
   ParametricPlot3D[
    {Sinc[a u/ k] u, v, k/a - k Cos[a u/k]/a}, {u, 0, 2 Pi k}, {v, 0, h},
    ImageSize -> {300, 300}, BoxRatios -> {k 3 \[Pi], h, 4 k},
    PlotRange -> {k {-\[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, {0, h}, k {0, 4}}, Mesh -> None,
    PlotStyle -> 
     Directive[Opacity[0.7], Orange, Specularity[White, 50]],
    ViewPoint -> {0, 1, -2}, ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0},
    BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Opacity[.3]]],

   ParametricPlot3D[
    Function[{u, v}, {Sinc[a u/ k] u, v, k/a - k Cos[a u/k]/a}] @@
     {Pi + t/10 Cos[t], Pi + t/10 Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 10 Pi}]},

 {{a, .01, "wrap"}, 0.001, 1},
 {{k, 2, "u-length"}, 0.1, 4},
 {{h, 1, "v-length"}, 0.1, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83103/discussion-on-answer-by-lllamnyp-is-there-a-way-to-animate-the-plane-wrapping-in).