# Deforming a unit square into a cylinder

Tags: graphics, manipulate, graphics3d, dynamic, polygons

I am new to Mathematica and I am trying to create a flat unit square in the x-z plane made out of polygons with vertices that divide it into equal-length intervals on each side. Then manipulate this plane into a cylinder with its axis along the z-direction.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate [Wrapping a rectangle to form a cylinder](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14828/125)?